# How to project these weird tiles onto a floor plane?

Tags: uv, fspy

I got these weird floor tiles that don't neatly align (ignore the other furniture in the pic).
[image]
A simple plane in blender is acting as the floor and I want its texture to be just these tiles

I tracked the camera in fspy and projected from its view the image onto the floor plane. The tiles the camera does see are textured correctly but they do not extend beyond the camera view, so how can I do that?

Trying what Mr A suggested leads to this:
[image]

Comment: ??? ... "but they do not extend beyond the camera"

Comment: The camera doesn't see the whole room, just a part of it, so most of the floor gets no texture projected onto it from the camera. These tiles are a repeatable pattern though and I need the entire floor to be made of them without needing to take pictures of every inch and make a bunch of projections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the ground texture would tile fine if you consider the section I marked in the image below. I am sure you know that you will still need to do some clean up in an image editing software to make the edges blend well.

[image: tile]

---

**Edit:** As mentioned in the comments, I failed to notice that the tiles also shift horizontally. I am also assuming that the tiles will align every `n1` tiles vertically and every `n2` tiles horizontally which may not be the case. I propose a different approach below that should work regardless.

1. Extract one tile from the ground texture. Give it clean dimensions  and parallel edges to make working with it easier.
2. The tiles have a bevel on two opposite vertices. Make sure that the edges they create are parallel and perfectly match. Give them clean dimensions as well.
3. Add an array modifier for horizontal tiling with constant offsets on x (tile width) and y (bevel height).
4. Add another array modifier for vertical tiling with constant offsets on x (bevel width)  and y (tile height).
5. Set the array count to as many as you need to cover the surface of interest.

I marked the important measurements in the screenshot below.

[image: Tile]

Bonus step: Modify the material shader to introduce variability to hide the fact that the whole floor was made from one tile worth of textures.

[image: Shader]

Here is the blend file:

[image]

Comment: This lines up perfectly (apart from the weird lighting) in the axis going towards the door, but it doesn't line up "horizontally". I tried to crop it such that it gets fixed but no. I think I need to somehow offset each horizontal tiling to make it work?

Comment: I am sorry. I failed to notice that the tiles shift horizontally as well. I gave this a second try and updated my answer. The new approach should work even if the tiles never line up.

Comment: Thank you for going above and beyond with additionally doing this nice shader!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

*It was quite challenging for me to understand what dimension and beveled angle, does the tiles to be repetitive texture (because like the MrA's answer is solving arraying the segment, the pattern is not going to be seamless texture.*

---

The solution is at the end trivial, you need the tile to be **7:6 aspect ratio**.
That also creates a beveled corners in 45°.

[image]

Arrayed for the first X7, Y1 and the second X1, Y6 ...

[image]

If you *Apply* modifiers and *Cut* (K) it in this way (texture or mesh doesnt matter) you get a pattern for seamless texture ...

[image]

[image]

[image]

UVmap can be set directly from source image ...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think making a tileable texture is simpler than the array method, plus you need less geometry so it is more optimized

Comment: Sure :) My point wasn't to advice you to work with geometry or texture, but mainly find a tile-able pattern of your floor. See edit.

Comment: Yep no worries, its good to have multiple ways to solve a problem.

Comment: Sure ... use what fits to your needs the best ... you can use MrA's solution for a single large image texture that is covering entire floor, but if you are looking for a way to create a seamless texture (that is what should generate real floor too) you can't get there with MrA's solution because his tiles are just arrayed and they never meet at rectangle edges (https://imgur.com/dS3Btxf) because his current aspect ratio doesnt allow such thing.

Comment: I agree with @vklidu, and I *+1* his solution. I was going to go this route, but started to doubt whether the original floor tiles were made to align at all. It's very hard to tell from the image we received. Ideally, we would have the dimensions of the tiles to answer this question. Anyway, I definitely agree that creating a seamless texture is better, since it can be used in more situations.

Comment: @MrA ... I agree, it could be much simpler solve it -to know the real tile dimension (I spent a few hours (again) by re-shaping tile back and forth, driving me crazy why I can't make it seamless (I thought just scale entire pattern in x or y should work, but it destroyed the seamlessnest on opposite side).